# Соседние клетки в гексагональном Тайлмапе

Tags: unity3d

Есть ли способ получить соседние клетки для заданной в Tilemap? Для гексагональной сетки используются прямоугольные координаты, но я не понимаю, как они распределяются, поэтому задать стандартное смещение не получается. Можно возвращать избыточно (т.е. 8, как для квадрата), но этот вариант мне не подходит.

Нутром чую, что ответ элементарный, а доказать не могу :)

Comment: А как выглядит нумерация клеток?

Comment: @MBo спасибо, я уже сам разобрался, готовлю ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался самостоятельно.

**TL;DR**

Так (если нужны ленивые вычисления):

```
IEnumerable<Vector3Int> GetNeighbours(Vector3Int cell){
    var yEven = cell.y % 2 == 0;

    yield return cell + new Vector3Int(+1, +0, 0); //горизонтальный правый
    yield return cell + new Vector3Int(-1, +0, 0); //горизонтальный левый
    yield return cell + new Vector3Int(+0, +1, 0); //диагональный верхний (для чётного ряда - правый, для нечётного - левый)
    yield return cell + new Vector3Int(+0, -1, 0); //диагональный нижний (для чётного ряда - правый, для нечётного - левый)

    yield return cell + yEven 
        ? new Vector3Int(-1, +1, 0)  //чётный ряд, диагональный верхний левый
        : new Vector3Int(+1, +1, 0); //нечётный ряд, диагональный верхний правый

    yield return cell + yEven 
        ? new Vector3Int(-1, -1, 0)   //чётный ряд, диагональный нижний левый
        : new Vector3Int(+1, -1, 0);  //нечётный ряд, диагональный нижний правый
}
```

Или, например, так (если нужен, например, массив):

```
 Vector3Int[] GetNeighbours(Vector3Int cell) => new [] {
      cell + new Vector3Int(+1, +0, 0),
      cell + new Vector3Int(+0, +1, 0),
      cell + new Vector3Int(-1, +0, 0),
      cell + new Vector3Int(+0, -1, 0),

      cell + cell.y % 2 == 0 ? new Vector3Int(-1, +1, 0) : new Vector3Int(+1, +1, 0),
      cell + cell.y % 2 == 0 ? new Vector3Int(-1, -1, 0) : new Vector3Int(+1, -1, 0)
  };
```

**Что тут происходит?**

Дело не в Unity и не в Tilemap, дело в принципе в использовании прямоугольных координатах для гексагональной сетки. В обычной сетке ячейки расположены так:

[image: Прямоугольная сетка]

В гексагональной (которая тоже прямоугольная, но хорошо маскируется) так:
[image: Гексагональная сетка]

Т.е., нечётные ряды там смещены вправо так, чтобы каждая ячейка имела не больше шести соседей. Соседи по оси X (горизонтальные) всегда будут вычисляться одинаково, т.к. они находятся в том же ряду. Соседи по Y (диагональные) для разных рядов вычисляются по разному. поскольку ряды смещены друг относительно друга в разные стороны.